# How can I test my website to see if it works on multiple browsers?

Tags: html, css

How can I test my website to see if it works on multiple browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [**BrowserStack**.com](http://www.browserstack.com) while browsing [jQuery.org](http://jquery.org). It's listet at their sponsors: http://jquery.org/sponsors/

I know it's a paid service, but there are no waiting times and your website won't appear in latest screenshots like on [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org).

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://browsershots.org/

You put in your URL and the browsers you want to check with.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better if you check yourself. There a number of free tools available online. For example http://browsershots.org

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test multiple versions of the same browser (e.g. IE8 on Windows XP Service Pack 1 and Windows XP Service Pack 2), something like BrowserShots as mentioned is good.

For a baseline of browsers though, you're going to want to actually have a machine running the browser. Think about what browsers are important when you're building your site. A lot of people have dropped IE6 support, but possibly for you (or your client), it's still required — take a look at real stats for this site in particular.

You need to think about what levels of support you'll give to each browser. Is it OK if something takes 1s in Chrome, but 3s in IE9, for example? Is it worth the effort to replace CSS gradients with image-based gradients in older browsers?

Finally, remember that while the likes of BrowserShots can help you with CSS, it can't check JavaScript, with browsers such as IE7 having a big performance hit versus Chrome or Firefox, especially with intensive graphics (such as SVG) or manipulation using XPath selectors (lacks native support).

**Nothing beats testing in a real browser**. While it sounds like the smart alec answer, this should be a minimum in your main browsers if you're working as a professional.